# Ubuntu/ Virtualenv/ Python3.4/ Gunicorn/ Nginx gunicorn ERROR: Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn

I have looked across the internet, including StackOverflow, and have seen similar problems, but after several hours I am stumped.

I can add in any information that anyone thinks might be of use. 
I am on DigitalOcean droplet Ubuntu14.0.4, in virtualenv named 'sod22', with Python3.4, Django1.8, Gunicorn19.4.5, nginx1.4.6
Here is my error output in Bash:

```
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# gunicorn --bind    0.0.0.0:8000 sod22.wsgi:application
[2016-01-27 02:25:18 -0500] [25609] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-01-27 02:25:18 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2016-01-27 02:25:18 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-01-27 02:25:19 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2016-01-27 02:25:19 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-01-27 02:25:20 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2016-01-27 02:25:20 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-01-27 02:25:21 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2016-01-27 02:25:21 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-01-27 02:25:22 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2016-01-27 02:25:22 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-01-27 02:25:23 -0500] [25609] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

I have checked for processes that might be running on port 8000 using netstat:

```
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3411/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14574/postgres  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25638/python3.4 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3411/sshd
```

I have killed all Gunicorn processes, but get the same behavior. However, with a different command my console seems to 'lock up' and there is still no output to the web page:

```
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# gunicorn sod22.wsgi:application
[2016-01-27 02:27:17 -0500] [25638] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-01-27 02:27:17 -0500] [25638] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (25638)
[2016-01-27 02:27:17 -0500] [25638] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-01-27 02:27:17 -0500] [25641] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25641
```

At that point there is no cursor to try anything else, without killing the console at this point.

Per Sayse's advice, I checked out the processes and results after killing processes. Maybe Python is using port:8000 and continuously refreshing after it is killed? See below, note that after the process is killed, I check again, and it is running again:

```
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3411/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14574/postgres  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25638/python3.4 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3411/sshd       
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# kill 25638
(sod22) root@ShapeOfData2:~/.virtualenvs/sod22# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3411/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14574/postgres  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25638/python3.4 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16069/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3411/sshd
```

Thanks in advance. Surely I'm not the only one that has experienced this!

Comment: That netstat appears to be showing your bottom snippet is using port 8000? Do you stop that process?

Comment: Yes- before the top snippet I had killed it. I just ran it again to show it for the copy/ paste that does show port 8000. So this process just started at the command: 'gunicorn sod22.wsgi:application'

Comment: Just to make sure its not gunicorn messing itself up... have you tried using a different port number?

Comment: That did work! I tries port 8002, and it served it from the remote host! I am going to paste in some other info, it almost seems like Gunicorn is starting back up on port 8000.

Comment: @Sayse - I just edited that last comment, will paste additional info.

Comment: Hmm that is strange, and not sure why it would do it (unless you're using something like supervisor that has an autoreload set which I don't think you do). You could try to rename the sod22.wsgi and then kill it since the gunicorn won't have any application to rerun, not convinced myself how much of a good idea that is though

Comment: I wonder if this could be the Django built-in server?

Comment: Django isn't a server, its a web framework so sorry that won't be the case

Comment: Ah, yes. I was only thinking of 'runserver,' which runs on 8000, I think. I am able to serve it up using port 8001, though. Perhaps this may be the solution for now. Thanks for your questions! They helped me see in a little better.

Comment: Yeah I realised after I wrote that comment you may have been referring to that and the only way that could be is if you had a different job running it (`fg` on centos, i don't know ubuntu) but I'd expect a kill to kill that "server" if so. Sorry couldn't be more help! If you do ever find a solution, feel free to post an answer to your own question :)

Comment: @Sayse Thank you for your help, I don't feel stuck now. I will post my eventual solution. It was 3am when I first posted, so had to take a break!!!